# Two foreign keys for one table | EF Core 6 | .NET 6

Tags: .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, relational-database

I try realize simple logic Contacts/Friends.

I have User table

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User()
    {

        UserContacts = new HashSet<UserContact>();
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; } 
    
    public virtual ICollection<UserContact> UserContacts { get; set; }
}
```

Table UserContact

```
public class UserContact : BaseEntity
{
  public Guid UserContactId { get; set; }

  public string FirstUserId { get; set; }

  public string SecondUserId { get; set; }

  public bool IsContact { get; set; }

  public bool IsWaitingAccept { get; set; }

  public string WaitingAcceptFromUserId { get; set; }

  public string BlockedByUserId { get; set; }

  public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }

  public virtual User FirstUser { get; set; }

  public virtual User SecondUser { get; set; }
}
```

My ApplicationDB Context

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserContact>(entity =>
        {
              entity.HasOne(c => c.FirstUser)
                    .WithMany(s => s.UserContacts)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.FirstUserId);
        });
```

As you can see I have relation only with FirstUser. If I add relation for `SecondUser`

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserContact>(entity =>
        {
              entity.HasOne(c => c.FirstUser)
                    .WithMany(s => s.UserContacts)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.FirstUserId);
              
              entity.HasOne(c => c.SecondUser)
                    .WithMany(s => s.UserContacts)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.SecondUserId);
        });
```

I have mistake on migration(I create DB CodeFirst by migration) and if I add it after migration have exception too.

[image: exception]

Basically diagrams in DataGrip show me the two relationships after migration with one relation in ApplicationDBContext

[image: diagrams]

[image: relations]

If I try to get all info from tables with include `UserContacts`

```
var result = await _db.User.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(u => u.UserContacts)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

It works good if my userId is in FirstUserId column and I have one record in

`public virtual ICollection<UserContact> UserContacts { get; set; }`

But if I try it for userId which in SecondUserId in result I haven't any records in

`UserContacts` property.

How need I create this logic right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't share a single Navigation Collection between two different Navigation Properties.

You need something like:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserContact>(entity =>
    {
          entity.HasOne(c => c.FirstUser)
                .WithMany(s => s.FirstUserContacts)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.FirstUserId);
          
          entity.HasOne(c => c.SecondUser)
                .WithMany(s => s.SecondUserContacts)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.SecondUserId);
    });
```